# Acronym placement in text and period

Tags: macros, text, renewcommand

I would like to define, an acronym that I can recycle in my text. E.g.,

```
\def\JB {\selectfont\texttt{J.~}-\texttt{Bond}}}
```

The problem is that,

- In the beginning or in the middle of the sentence, I'd have to use \JB~ to create a space after "J. Bond" and alternatively,
- I can define `\def\JB {\selectfont\texttt{J.~}-\texttt{Bond~}}}` so that I can avoid "\JB~" but then, this will create issues at the end of the sentence where "\JB" if followed by a period, yielding "J. Bond ."

Would there be a way to program this in a way that \JB inserts a space after \JB when used in the begining/middle of the sentence and no space if it is followed by a period?

Comment: Why `\selectfont` and why `-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `xspace` package and then you can define

```
\def\JB {\selectfont\texttt{J.~}-\texttt{Bond}\xspace}
```

If you compile the LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\def\JB {\selectfont\texttt{J.~}-\texttt{Bond}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\JB will always be \JB.
\end{document}
```

you will get a space after the first J. Bond, but not after the second one.

Of course, a more LaTeX-ish way of doing things is to define your command this way:

```
\newcommand*{\JB}{\selectfont\texttt{J.~}-\texttt{Bond}\xspace}
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. This is so helpful.